# how scons pass sysroot to g++

Tags: c++, android-ndk, cross-platform, scons

I had set sysroot in CXXFLAGS
and when compile object file I can see sysroot in cmd line
but when build elf I cann't find the sysroot in cmd line, so build failed

so how can I pass sysroot in scons rightly?

Answer (score 2):

SCons has a variety of flags that can be set for the different tasks, and you can always add your own if you need. As you correctly figured out, CXXFLAGS is used when compiling files...but not for linking. You'll have to add your flag to LINKFLAGS...a rather complete list of all available variables and their meaning can be found in the UserGuide ( http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html ). Also note that there is a second set of flags/variables for shared objects (SHCXXFLAGS/SHLINKFLAGS).